# How to get the count of the selected nodes not the root

Tags: javascript, tree

How to get the count of only the selected nodes(child nodes) not the root nodes in tree java-script ?

Comment: Can you add a code example? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this property childElementCount to get how many children in an element

but if you wanna only check if there are children or not you can use this method hasChildNodes(), it returns true or false

```js
console.log(document.body.childElementCount);
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
```